# Checking if images is loaded or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, onload

I want that my javascript code should wait until images are loaded

Code:

```
function imagess(url ,callback)
{

var img = new Image();

    img.onError = function() {
        alert('Cannot load image: "'+url+'"');
    };
    img.crossOrigin = '';
    img.onload = function() {
        callback(img);

    };
    img.src = url;
}
while(img.isonload){
do nothing no code should execute}
```

The above code will run on chrome will it be good practice to use while loops?

Comment: img.onload will wait uptil the image will be loaded and then it execute callback ,i want that uptill that time no code should executed

Comment: You need to use the callback to initialize the next step. While loop is just going to freeze the page.

Comment: would you please please explain in brief

Comment: ya i know that i have not posted that code

Comment: The only way you can wait for code to run is to call it in the callback. There is no way to do a while loop in JavaScript that waits for it to be loaded. What are you REALLY trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

```
img.onload = function() {
        img.onload = true;
        callback(img);    
};

function callback(img){
    while(img.onload)
    {
       // what do you want
       // complete your work and img.onload set false for stop execution of loop
    }

}
```

when unload function execute then callback is calling and it do your stuff

Comment: This code will run on chrome browser 10-12 images will be used? Will it will crash the browser or not?

Comment: paste code on fiddle this is best to identify your problem